# Can't output entire stream in C++

Tags: c++

The program that I will be creating will get the currently logged in username on the UNIX/Linux system and display a welcome message. What the code blow is doing is executing only this:

```
Welcome user@hostname:~/Dev/cpp$
```

The rest of the stream is not outputted. What do I need to do to be able to output the rest of it? Should I use some other function instead of this one? I'm not sure I should even use getenv() for this.

I suppose I could use regex or something to get only the username, but that doesn't solve the problem though the rest of the stream is not outputted anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
     std::cout << "Welcome " << getenv("USERNAME") << " to APP_NAME. To get     available commands use --help" << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _"the rest of the stream is not outputted"_? It just works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68987d40b6e117bd).

Comment: I'm confused by this output. `USERNAME` is not a standard environment variable. `USER` is supposed to hold the name of the current user, but even this is optional. I'm suspecting that `getenv` gives you a `nullptr` and you're invoking undefined behavior. Check the `return` value.

Comment: What contains that `USERNAME` environment variable ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, that's weird. When I compile it and run the program I only get ouput of to the getenv() function and not the other string that should come after it.

Comment: @5gon12eder Aaah, you're right. The whole stream works perfectly when I used only USER instead of USERNAME. Thanks!

Comment: Try altering `USERNAME` to `XYZ` or something else nonsensical in the example @πάνταῥεῖ has linked to. It will also truncate after the `Welcome` then, thus supporting my hypothesis. It just so happens that this online-service runs in an environment where `USERNAME` is set. I understand now that `user@hostname:~/Dev/cpp$` is your normal shell prompt that shows up after the truncated output of your program that doesn't end with a new-line.

Comment: @Kdoel Well, your program should test the `return` value anyway. You cannot rely on these variables to be set.

Comment: @5gon12eder Alright, I will add that then. Add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're executing the program in an environment where the `USERNAME` variable is not set (which does not surprise me). Therefore [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) `return`s a `nullptr` and streaming this unchecked to `std::cout` gives undefined behavior which, in your case, happens to truncate the stream. The `user@hostname:~/Dev/cpp$` you're seeing is not produced by your program but your ordinary shell prompt that ends up in a funny position because the program ended abruptly without outputting a final new-line.

You should test the `return` value before using it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  if (const auto user = std::getenv("USERNAME"))
    std::cout << "Hello, " << user << "\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Hello, whoever you may be.\n";
}
```

Anyway, this is not how you're supposed to obtain the user name of the currently logged in user. If you want to use the environment (which is not reliable) you should use the `USER` variable instead. A probably more robust solution would be to use the [`getlogin`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getlogin.html) function specified by POSIX and provided via `<unistd.h>`. Note that `getlogin` may also fail (`return` a `nullptr`) so you should still have a backup strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible cause is that the environment variable `USERNAME` does not exist when you execute your program. The `getenv` function returns then a `nullptr` (as suggested by @5gon12eder) and you invoke undefined behaviour by injecting a `nullptr` in an output stream. In your example, it just ends the output (like if it was inserting a null in a string), in my own one, if raises a SIGSEGV.

You should ensure that the environment variable exists:

```
int main() {
     const char *name = getenv("USERNAME");
     if (name == std::nullptr) { name = "unknown guest"; }
     std::cout << "Welcome " << name << " to APP_NAME. To get     available commands use --help" << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```